# Passing Row Data from Oro Crm/ Platform Data Grid to a Controller

Tags: symfony, orocrm

I have created a data grid and showing data using `oro/data_grids.yml` configuration

```
datagrids:
app-demo-grid:
    source:
        type: orm
        query:
            select:
                - po.itemId
                - po.itemName
                - po.itemDescription

            from:
                - { table: DemoBundle:PurchaseOrder, alias: po }
    columns:
        itemId:
            label: Item ID
            frontend_type: integer
        itemName:
            label: Item Name
            frontend_type: string

    actions:
        send:
            type: navigate
            label: Send to Url
            link: send_link
            icon: send
            rowAction: true
```

The problem: Passing parameter to the controller from grid action - send is not working. There are no more parameters in my request.

Answer (score 1):

You should configure property "send_link".

```
app-demo-grid:
    source:
        type: orm
        query:
            select:
                - po.itemId
                - po.itemName
                - po.itemDescription

            from:
                - { table: DemoBundle:PurchaseOrder, alias: po }
    columns:
        itemId:
            label: Item ID
            frontend_type: integer
        itemName:
            label: Item Name
            frontend_type: string
    properties:
        send_link:
            type:   url
            route:  your_route_for_send_link_action
            params:
                id: itemId
    actions:
        send:
            type: navigate
            label: Send to Url
            link: send_link
            icon: send
            rowAction: true
```

For more information about properties configuration please have a look at this [documentation](https://github.com/oroinc/platform/blob/master/src/Oro/Bundle/DataGridBundle/Resources/doc/backend/datagrid.md#columns-and-properties).